# External References to SQL tables in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a solution that includes a database project linked to an Azure database.  The project requires setting up an elastic query to a separate table in a different Azure Database.  This all exists already in Azure.  I have imported the database using the visual studio wizard.  It's imported the external table definition and the external data source, but not the masterkey or the scoped credential.  I fully understand why as it's a security risk.  However, I now can't publish my changes to the stored procedures etc as the external data sources have syntax errors where the scoped credentials are not defined.  I've tried adding the masterkey and scoped credentials to my database project but the same syntax I used in the SQL management studio is not working in Visual Studio.

So my question is... how am I supposed to manage the external tables in my azure database in visual studio? I should mention that I am using VS2015. Is this functionality that is not working yet or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give.

Answer (score 0):

Although SSDT gives a syntax error, can you verify that you can still build the project? The syntax error seems to be a intelliSense parser problem which shouldn't block build or deployment. Please let me know if it works.

**Disclaimer:** I work on the SSDT/DacFx team.